# JPA Fetch a Parent Entity from a Child Entity with Child Entity having Composite Primary Key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading

I have Parent Entity (EntityA) which looks something like this below.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Entity_A")
    Public Class EntityA {
    
    private Integer entityAId;
    private String name;
    private Set<EntityB> entityB = new Hashset<>();

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(....)
    @Column(name = "ENTITY_A_ID", ...)
    public Integer getEntityAId() {
       return entityAId;
    }
    public void setEntityAId(Integer entityAId) {
       this.entityAId = entityAId;
    }

    **// Setter and Getter for name**

    @OnetoMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.Lazy, mappedBy = "entityA")
    public set<EntityB> getEntityB() {
       return this.entityB;
    }

    }
```

Following is the Sample Code of Child Entity(Entity B).

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Entity_B")
    Public Class EntityB {
     
       private EntityBCompositeId entityBCompositeId;
       private EntityA entityA;

       @EmbeddedId
       @AttributeOverride(name = "code", column = @Column(name = "CODE", nullable = false))
       @AttributeOverride(name = "entityIdA", column= @Column(name = "ENTITY_A_ID", nullable= false))
       public EntityBCompositeId getEntityBCompositeId() {
          return this.entityBCompositeId;
       }
       public void setEntityBCompositeId(EntityBCompositeId entityBCompositeId) {
          this.entityBCompositeId = entityBCompositeId;
       }
       
       @OnetoOne
       @JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY_A_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
       @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
       @LazyGroup("entityASet")
       public EntityA getEntityA() {
          return entityA;
       }
       
       public void setEntityA(EntityA entityA) {
          this.entityA = entityA;
       }
    }
```

Following is the code for EntityBCompositeId

```
    @Embeddable
    public class EntityBCompositeId {
       private Integer entityAId;
       private String code;
       
       @Column(name = "ENTITY_A_ID", nullable = false)
       public Integer getEntityAId() {
          return this.entityAId;
       }
       public void setEntityAId(EntityAId entityAId) {
          this.entityAId = entityAId;
       }
       
       @Column(name = "CODE", nullable = false)
       public Integer getCode() {
          return this.code;
       }
       public void setCode(String code) {
          this.code = code;
       }
    }
```

I have List of child entites(EntityB) which iam iterating and filtering based on the Column CODE and converting the Entity to a DTO. Something like this

```
    1. Public ServiceClass {
    2.    convertEntityToDtoMethod() {
    3.      entityBList.forEach(entityB -> 
    4.         if(entityB.getEntityBCompositeId().getCode().equals("ABC"))) {
    5.             setNameToDto(entityB.getEntityA().getName());
    6.             ...set the remaning values to DTO
    7.         }
    8.    }
    9. }
```

The issue here is as the EntityA is Lazily loaded in EntityB for all the iterations done on EntityB and when i try to get the Name from EntityA (Line Number 5 above) a new Select Query is generated by hibernate every time as hibernate loads the LazyLoaded entites only we call get..() something like this below.

```
     select ENTITY_A_ID from ENTITY_B where ENTITY_A_ID=? and CODE=?
     select ENTITY_A_ID from ENTITY_B where ENTITY_A_ID=? and CODE=?
     select ENTITY_A_ID from ENTITY_B where ENTITY_A_ID=? and CODE=?
     ......
     ......
```

Is there any way i can Load all these Child entities at once instead of multiple Select Queries??

Answer (score 0):

You could use entity graphs(https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-graph) or `JOIN FETCH` in your query, but since you are converting to a DTO, I can recommend you take a look at [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(EntityA.class)
public interface EntityADto {
    @IdMapping
    Integer getEntityAId();
    String getName();
    @Mapping("entityB")
    Set<EntityBDto> getBs();

    @EntityView(EntityB.class)
    interface EntityBDto {
        @IdMapping
        EntityBCompositeIdView getId();
        // other mappings...
    }
    @EntityView(EntityBCompositeId.class)
    interface EntityBCompositeIdView {
        Integer getEntityAId();
        String getCode();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`EntityADto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, EntityADto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features